# Умножение на ассемблере с помощью сдвигов

Tags: ассемблер

Как умножить на ассемблере число ABCD на число 32 с помощью сдвигов?

Comment: SHLD с count = 5?

Answer (score 4):

Вот вам великолепная книжка, наслаждайтесь: "Язык ассемблера для процессоров Intel, 4-е издание". Второй вопрос на ту же тему.

```
mov eax, 0ABCDh
shl eax, 5h
```